# Web.config overwritten

Tags: web-config

I have a web.config for my website. I just made a web service which likes to overwrite the previous one. From what I can understand I need an xml transform here. I have read several sites and I am confused as how to complete this. [One reference](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/search?q=xml+transforms). Would love some insight, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1755461/169714 I don't get the question. is it that you have a webservice running on the same server as your website and that you would like to call the webservice to change the web.config of the website?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add or change something in web.config you don't need any XSL(T) because your output format is still XML.
Transformation (XSLT) is mainly for presenting XML data in different format.
What yo need is basic XML editing functionality. Parse to DOM, add/change nodes, save.

Comment: While I can edit the web.config for the web site, VS makes all the changes to the config for the web service behind the scenes and just overwrites the one on the server. How do I blend them together? Maybe I used the wrong term above.

Comment: @MadnessIsMine do you have vs2010 or 2012rc? and do you have web.config.debug and web.config.release? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2791271/169714